# How can I prove $\sum\limits_{x \in f^{-1}(y)}\mkern-9mu \operatorname{sgn}(d_xf)=1$?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

**Definition:** If $M \subset \mathbb{R}^k$ and $N \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ are two smooth oriented varieties and if $f: M \to N$ is smooth then we define
$$ \operatorname{sgn}(d_x f)=
\begin{cases}
\phantom{-}1 &\mbox{ if it brings a positive oriented basis to a positive oriented basis,}\\
-1 &\mbox{ otherwise. }\\
\end{cases}$$

**My problem:** Let be $\mathbb{D}^n$ be the closed unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and
$$s: \mathbb{D}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n+1}-\{0\}$$ defined as follow

$$s(x)=(e^{-\frac{1}{1-\|x\|^2}}x,1-2e^{1-\frac{1}{1-\|x\|^2}})$$
for $\|x\|<1$ and $s(x)=(0,...,0,1)$ for $\|x\|=1$.

Define $g(x)=\frac{s(x)}{\|s(x)\|}$ and $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{S}^n$ defined as follow:

$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
g(x) &\mbox{ if } x \in \mathbb{D}^n, \\
(0,...,0,1) &\mbox{ otherwise. }
\end{cases}$$

It is clear that $f$ is a smooth map between varieties. Suppose $y \in \mathbb{S}^n$ is a regular value for $f$. How can I prove $\sum\limits_{x \in f^{-1}(y)} \operatorname{sgn}(d_xf)=1$?

Comment: First of all, $s$ is not defined on the boundary of the ball.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for your comment, I edited the question.